# Resharper doesn't work on visual studio 2013?

Tags: resharper

Certainly Resharper Tools Totally Doesn't Work on my VS-13 IDE.
I already uninstall VS-13, and reinstall, and Apply all kinds of solution that I got from Stack Overflow, but nothing change.
On the other hand, Resharper clearly working on VS-15 on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check both checkboxes "vs 2013" and "vs 2015" during resharper installation?

Answer (score 0):

For VS-13, Use just R# 8.0/ 9.0, then it's fully working on VS-13.
And For VS-15, Use R# 9.0/10.0++.... It Solved.

Comment: That doesn't seem right as the latest version of ReSharper (2016.1) works with all versions of Visual Studio from 2010 upwards (ReSharper 8 is the last version that worked with VS2005 and VS2008). I am currently running ReSharper 2016.1 on VS2010 Pro, VS2012 Pro, VS2013 Pro and VS2015 Enterprise.